# Surface Pro 3 Battery

Tags: battery, 15.04, surface

I installed 15.04, everything is running smoothly. One issue, however, is that I have no battery notifier on either gnome nor unity.

Q: How could I begin to trouble shoot this, if there is no fix, is there another app that I could install that will do the same thing?

Comment: I own a surface 3 pro, you can find a how to for fixing all the things that do not work [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/620726/ubuntu-on-surface-pro-3-or-linux-at-all/620741#620741).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Github user neoreeps has been kind enough to include all the patchs, with instructions, in one place.

https://github.com/neoreeps/surface-pro-3

Answer (score 1):

First, check and see if you have a battery entry in /proc/.

```
ls /proc/acpi/
```

If the list you get back includes a 'battery' entry you can run:

```
cat /proc/acpi/battery/
```

Which will return the information on the battery.

Secondly, if the above `ls /proc/acpi` doesn't include an entry for 'battery' than you can install acpi with:

```
sudo apt-get install acpi
```

Once installed (you may need to reboot) you should be able to run:

```
acpi -b
```

and this will return the battery level information.

For more info on the acpi command, run `man acpi`

Comment: Thank you for this. Unfortunately, it's a kernel related issue. There are patches available which I'll explain in my answer.