# Touchscreen with two fingers?

Tags: multi-touch, touchscreen

Is it possible (and how?) to make ubuntu/linux/xorg identify 2 finger taps on a touchscreen (read SCREEN, not touchpad)?
I tried easystroke to get click+hold popup a rightclick menu (executing xdotool click 3) like in windows, but that destroyed the 1 finger scroll in every program that supported it out of the box.

I would rather have 1 finger scroll and at same time click+hold for rightclick menu but it seems impossible. So my plan was to use 2 finger to scroll and 1 finger click+hold for rightclick menu.

Is it possible? I have been googling for several days now, so either nobody else is using touchscreens with linux or my google-fu is awful.....

I am using ubuntu-gnome, not unity (in case someone knows of a gnome-specific solution)

Comment: i dunno how to solve that issue, however i strongly recommend you not to use ubuntu on a touchscreen pc, it wouldn't be beneficial and you won't take the most out of your pc

Comment: Thanks. I have been considering it for very long, and now with 15.10 it actually is very much touchfriendly than before. I found Gnome to fullfill all my needs for the touchinterface except the one I am asking for above. Hoping there is some fix for it so I do not have to wait more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 15.10 works perfectly with multi-touch events (for instance, 3 allow to move a certain window, 4 opens the bash). If you are having problems with it, it has probably to do with the driver you are using or the multi-touch capabilities of the display.

Which device are you testing with? Can you post the output of `xinput --list`?

Regards

**EDIT:**

In order to get full touch functionality with a surface pro and as stated in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/620726/ubuntu-on-surface-pro-3-or-linux-at-all) :

Download 4.0.1 Kernel sources from [here](https://www.kernel.org/) and the patches from [here](http://www.datafilehost.com/d/0828e07e).
Extract both files to a new directory. `tar xvf archive.tar.gz /foler`
Install tools with `sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev kernel-package`
Apply all the patches with `patch -p1 -i xxx.patch`
Copy the current config with:

```
cp /boot/config-`uname -r` .config
```

Run `make menuconfig` then press <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>ESC</kbd> to save and exit.
Start the compiling with:

```
make-kpkg clean
fakeroot make-kpkg --initrd --append-to-version=-surface-pro-3 kernel_image kernel_headers
```

Compiling can take 1-2 hours, depending on your pc. If you have a dualcore you can add `-j 2` after make-kpkg, `-j 4` if you have a quadcore.
Make will then use the number of cores you specify.

Once it is done you will have two `.deb` files.
Install them with `sudo dpkg -i linux-image*.deb linux-headers*.deb`

Reboot your system and select the newly compield Kernel while booting.

Comment: I am using Surface Pro 3. The multitouch works perfect on touchpad and on screen. I can use all the 3 finger events, and the usual scroll with 1x, etc etc. I just cannot seem to find how to bind 2 fingers to do anything.

I want to bind 2x fingers to scroll instead of 1x finger, so that I can use that 1x for rightclick when click+hold (this I can do with easystroke). But how do I rebind scrolling to 2x fingers?

Comment: Hmm!  I guess a long press does not achive the desired effect? I'll get back to you as soon as I can test it myself with my two touch devices (Linux Minut & Ubuntu). Cheers

Comment: I can confirm a long press works in Ubuntu 15.10 and Linux Mint Rebecca 64bit as right click (using an eGalax Touchscreen-display). It looks like you need to perform kernel modifications in order to have full functionality in surface pro. I'll edit the post.